# Open Graph product schema enum property values

Tags: facebook, schema, facebook-opengraph, product, pinterest

I would like to know what are the **allowed values for the Open Graph `og:product` type, `og:availability` property**. It is defined as an enum property (see http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/product#availability).

I have struggled for a while trying to make Open Graph product tags work according to Pinterest Rich Pins specification without any success. (see http://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/ -> Open Graph -> availability). The example there works fine, both Facebook and Pinterest debuggers parse it correctly.

```
<meta property="og:availability" content="instock" />
```

But if this value is changed by any of the ones which are described in the Rich Pins documentation (in stock", "preorder", "backorder", "out of stock", "discontinued"). Both Facebook and Pinterest debuggers fail to parse the content of this `og:availability` property.

Also the documented value documented in Rich Pins for the meta tag property looks wrong to me but `og:availability` and `product:availability` are valid ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest version of the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/) lists the following as valid values for the `og:availability` property: `instock`, `oos`, `pending`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right documentation, still Pinterest does not recognize those values but Facebook validator does. That is a Pinterest problem. So this is the valid answer

Comment: Link seems to be broken

Comment: @TizioFittizio Seven years later, this content seems to now be available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference#og-tags) but my answer is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for "instock" is "in stock" with space.  After many tries, and consulting the product Schema, this works.